# Encapsulating Logic in SQL - Best Practice

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Greetings and thanks for reading!

I was wondering what the best practice for encapsulating stored procedure logic using a set-based SQL technique.

For example, I have a product entry application that I am developing.  While attempting to limit code duplication, I created a stored procedure called AddItem which creates a new product in the product tables.  The downside is that in order to utilize this procedure in a situation that requires adding a group of products, I am forced to use a cursor or WHILE loop to execute the procedure in a "FOR EACH" type of way.  This is resulting in very poor performance on large sets of items.

Of course I could hard-code the INSERT statements into the calling procedure but that makes me feel icky because the whole point is to be able to change (in one place) the "add item" logic.  So if a column changed I would have to remember to change all of the INSERT statements in all of the places that use it.  I just figured there has to be a better way of doing this and any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Quite right, I should provide a code example.  Here is the contents of the AddItem procedure which is being executed on a MS SQL2005 database:

```
            ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddItem]
                @ProjectNumber  int,
                @ItemName       varchar(255),
                @SupplierID     int,
                @SKUType        int,
                @Store          varchar(3),
                @Category       varchar(4),
                @AddedBy        varchar(255),
                @ParentSKU      varchar(255) = NULL,
                @SetNumber      int = NULL,
                @NewItemNumber  int OUTPUT
            AS  
                SET NOCOUNT ON

                DECLARE @DiscontinuedStatus bit

                BEGIN TRY
                    BEGIN TRAN
                        SET @NewItemNumber = 0

                        INSERT INTO ProductEntry.dbo.Items
                        (ProjectNumber, SetNumber, SKUType, Store, Category, AddedBy, ParentSKU, EntryTime)
                        VALUES(@ProjectNumber, @SetNumber, @SKUType, @Store, @Category, @AddedBy, @ParentSKU, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

                        SET @NewItemNumber = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

                        IF @SKUType = 1
                        BEGIN
                            SET @DiscontinuedStatus = 1
                        END
                        ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @DiscontinuedStatus = 0
                        END 

                        INSERT INTO ProductEntry.dbo.ItemInfo
                        (ItemNumber, ItemName, Discontinued)
                        VALUES (@NewItemNumber, @ItemName, @DiscontinuedStatus)

                        INSERT INTO ProductEntry.dbo.ItemSupplierInfo   
                        (ItemNumber, SupplierID)
                        VALUES(@NewItemNumber, @SupplierID)

                        INSERT INTO ProductEntry.dbo.ItemWebInfo
                        (ItemNumber)
                        VALUES(@NewItemNumber)

                        INSERT INTO ProductEntry.dbo.ItemTags
                        (ItemNumber)
                        VALUES (@NewItemNumber)
                    COMMIT TRAN
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    ROLLBACK TRAN
                END CATCH
```

I have a need for a procedure that adds multiple items at a time (with numbers greater than 1000) and when using a cursor the performance is very bad.  It takes over a minute to add a group of 800 products and it only gets worse from there.

EDIT:
To further clarify the solution, the application allows items that have a parent-child relationship.  When adding a new parent item, the user selects from a list of options and a set of child items is generated based on the option set.

For example, a user could create a product called "Awesome Boot" with an option set of Colors="Brown, Black", Size="10M, 11M, 12M", ToeStyle="SteelToe, SoftToe" - this would generate a set of 12 items.  Obviously you can see how this could increase exponentially, considering that most boots have around 36 sizes, multiple colors and toe styles, as well as other options.  This can result in a parent item with a large number of child items.

I guess one solution would be to combine all of the different item information into one "Items" table, eliminating the need for storing the same IDENTITY in multiple tables.  I kind of like the convenience of splitting up the related data logically into different tables though.  Maybe I'm trying to have my cake and eat it too!

Thanks! :)

Comment: More info needed, why are you using a cursor, give us sample data and expected results.  We may be able to help with a better set based solution.

Comment: The answer to your question will largely depend on the database you are using. Different technologies have different techniques to do this kind of thing. Please specify the database you are using. If you want a general answer, I would say, no to the cursor or the while loop, you can probably do `insert into table (col,col,col..) values (val,val,val...),(val,val,val...)`

Comment: Problem 1: stored proc = procedural = antithesis of set-based. Problem 2: SQL: has but one data structure = the table <> a type i.e. can't generally speaking pass a table as a parameter to a proc; sure, SQL Server (for example) has table variables but can't be directly used in you 3GL language of choice (e.g. C#.NET).

Comment: onedaywhen: Yes, it's clear that I'm not using SQL the way it is meant to be used.  That's why I was wondering what people normally do in a situation like this - push the logic to the application layer?  If so, I'll have to hard-code the insert statements which is kind of a bugger.

Comment: Problem 3: use of IDENTITY means key values cannot be bulk generated outside of the DBMS.

Comment: Problems 1 and 2 are big ones, not within your control and with no easy answers, I'm afraid :)

Comment: Group of 800 products in about a minute is bad? I consider that pretty good considering the solution you posted.  I was more looking at you posting exactly what the requirements are.  Details like what makes the UI pass 800 items to the procedure?  Give us a nice detailed post showing exact details, screen shots, or something to help us come up with a set based solution.

Comment: I have a couple of specific questions - well one really about two tables. What is the purpose of storing just the `IDENTITY` value in the `ItemWebInfo` and `ItemTags` tables?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrant: Short answer: This is the way the DBA set it up. :)  Better answer: To logically separate the different classes of item data.  I see your point that it might make sense to combine all of the data into one "Items" table with a large number of columns.

Comment: @Vince I don't understand what "all of the data" is... you've only inserted the identifier into these two tables, what other data is there? Is there data you'll later affect with updates only?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrant: Oh, sorry, I see what you mean!  The tables are configured with DEFAULT constraints that set practical starting values.  When adding a new item, I create "empty" rows in all of the item tables and then UPDATE the tables as the user changes the data.

Comment: @Vince unless those tables will eventually have multiple rows per entity, I think it would make a lot more sense (at least in most cases - there are always exceptions) if those columns were in the primary table.

Comment: @Aaron: That is a great suggestion because the items will only ever have one row per table.  I will discuss this with the DBA as it sounds like the correct solution is to simplify our table structure.  If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a stray comment - the two tables ItemWebInfo and ItemTags - unless those tables will eventually have multiple rows per entity, I think it would make a lot more sense (at least in most cases - there are always exceptions) if those columns were in the primary table. I also might suggest the same for the supplierInfo, unless an item can have more than one supplier the supplierID should just be a column in the primary table as well.

Comment: That seems like the correct solution - no sense in having the same IDENTITY split across multiple tables.  Great answer.  By simplifying the table structure I can drastically simplify the stored procedure or eliminate it entirely.